# How to implement backtrace function in linux for printing stack trace on crash

Tags: c++

As i am using an older version of kernel so the backtrace function of glibc is not working so i want to get some direction for implementation of function in c/c++ language and linux os...

Comment: How dirty are you ready to get your hands?

Comment: i want to solve the problem at any cost...

Comment: One way would be to add a macro to the beginning and another to the end of each function, in which you keep track of the function stack (using `__func__` macro for example). This is the only manual way I can think of that is standard-compliant.

Comment: But the problem is actually i want to do this to release version...and the project is on delivery phase...

Comment: Then you are probably stuck with hacking the call stack based on your target architecture/os/compiler. I am no expert in this, but perhaps the source code for gdb would have the answer, since it does what you want.

Comment: Or maybe the source code of valgrind